# How to detect if token is expired or not registred firebase FCM notification on app server?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using following code to send the FCM notification from server to device :

```
    String fcmServerKey = externalConfig.getFcmServerKey();
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(HTTPS_FCM_GOOGLEAPIS_COM_FCM_SEND);

            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, ContentType.create("application/json")));
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "key=" + fcmServerKey);

CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse= httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

In above code when I get the response object `closeableHttpResponse`, how can I detect wether the fcm token used to send this request is expired or not registered ?

When from firebase application dashboard I try sending the notification to a device using its fcm token and After application is removed from device, I see `Failed` on firebase dashboard, on hovering cursor on `Failed` I see `Unregistered registration token`.

How can I detect above error situation of `Unregistered registration token` from api response object `closeableHttpResponse` ?

Comment: Have you seen the sample code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31659073/4625829)?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Server Reference API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#example_get_request) to get the associated information about the device registration token. If the response is empty, it means that the token is expired or not registered.

Example GET request

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/nKctODamlM4:...clJONHoA?details=true
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

Example result

```
HTTP 200 OK
  {
    "application":"com.iid.example",
    "authorizedEntity":"123456782354",
    "platform":"Android",
    "attestStatus":"ROOTED",
    "appSigner":"1a2bc3d4e5",
    "connectionType":"WIFI",
    "connectDate":"2015-05-12
    "rel":{
        "topics":{
          "topicname1":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"},
          "topicname2":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"},
          "topicname3":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"},
          "topicname4":{"addDate":"2015-07-30"}
                  }
           }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

create this class in your package

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
import com.google.gson.Gson;



public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";


    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);



    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //if token is already inserted then update token in your server

    }


}
```

and add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in

```
<application>
        ..............
        <service
            android:name=".Listeners.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

</application>
```

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() use this code to get FCM ID instantly

Comment: Hi Babul thanks, my problem is not how to detect new token, how to detect expired or unregistered token on server

Comment: As the OP mentioned, this answer is not related with the solution.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.