# How can I know who uninstall push notifications with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I send a web push notification with fcm google api and the user has uninstalled the application I receive a **"NotRegistered" error message**.

I want to know this information without send any push notification, is this possible? Create some php code to run every day and know how many user i'm losing per day.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442434/firebase-cloud-messaging-how-to-validate-tokens) say there is no way to validate tokens without sending a message, although one answer mentions the ability to perform a dry run. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43889697/how-to-detect-if-token-is-expired-or-not-registred-firebase-fcm-notification-on) shows a separate REST endpoint that can check. As a final alternative, you can send a data message, which your app then ignores, to perform the test.