# Apache HttpClient : Unable to close the connection

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using `HttpClient 4.5.10` and below is the code snippet that is used to make a `GET` request:

```
public String executeRequest(HttpRequestBase request, Header... headers) {
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = execute(request, headers)) {
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to execute request: " + request.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

I use `lsof` to monitor connections and this results in a new connection in `ESTABLISHED` state. Once the request gets executed, the connection moves into `CLOSE_WAIT` state but doesn't go away. Subsequent calls keep adding more connections to the list.

The question is, how do I make sure that the connection gets released back to pool (I use `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`)? Do I need to explicit close the request as well, e.g.:

```
public String executeRequest(HttpRequestBase request, Header... headers) {
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = execute(request, headers)) {
        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to execute request: " + request.toString(), e);
    } finally {
        request.releaseConnection();
    }
}
```

**Update**

I have applied the above approach (i.e. `request.releaseConnection()`). However, I still see the open connections usin `lsof`. Looks like the connections are still there.

Is there anything else I need to do to explicitly close the connections?

Comment: You are already using try-with-resources. That is sufficient. If you don't already know that it is difficult to see why you are using the construct at all.

Comment: Yes, try-with-resources *should* be sufficient. However, despite of the above code, I am seeing open connection after each request, hence the question.

Comment: Do you see more connections in lsof than your pool size?

Comment: Nope, once it hits the threshold, all the subsequent requests to acquire connection fail. The only way to fix it is to restart the process.

Comment: It's almost certainly doing HTTP connection pooling. Wait for the pool timeout, or change it.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed doing the connection pooling. However, each call of the above method seems to take one connection from pool and never releases it. This results in pool getting exhausted (eventually) and I then need to restart the process. My question is, what else should I do in the above code so that it **releases** the connection back to pool?

Comment: What happened when you tried `releaseConnection()`?

Comment: I haven't tried `releaseConnection()`. The question is about *should I try it*? The documentation for that says it's just a convenience method.

Comment: So why *don't* you try it? You can't seriously believe that asking questions on the Internet is more efficient than conducting your own experiments.

Comment: The reason is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889984/whats-the-difference-between-closeablehttpresponse-close-and-httppost-release/31659073#31659073) answer which says it's not recommended to use this method. Of course I can try it but wanted to explore the alternatives if anyone faced this issue before.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I have updated the question with my findings.