# Apache HttpClient not receiving entire response

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, chunked-encoding

**Update:** If I use `System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));` the output is what appears to be the missing lines of HTML (including the closing `body` and `html` tags). However, printing to a file still only gives me the first 2000 odd lines missing the last 1000.

---

I am using the following code to perform a http post request:

```
public static String Post(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, String url, Header[] headers,
            List<NameValuePair> data, HttpClientContext context) throws IOException
{
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
    httpPost.setHeaders(headers);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, context);

    if (response.getEntity() == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Unable to get html for: " + url);

    // Get the data then close the response object
    String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    response.close();

    return responseData;
}
```

However I am not receiving the full response entity. I am missing about 1000 lines of html (including the closing `body` and `html` tags. **I think this is because the data is being sent in chunks although I am not entirely sure.**

Here are the response headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Connection:Transfer-Encoding
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 04 Jul 2015 15:14:58 GMT
Expires:Sat, 04 Jul 2015 15:14:58 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:User-Agent
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

How can I ensure that I receive the full response entity?

Comment: Share code for saving into file - there must by an error

Comment: @WandMaker definetly no

Comment: @WandMaker I don't think so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969037/why-did-the-author-use-entityutils-consumehttpentity

Comment: @Antoniossss you were right. Originally I was using a single line creating a printwriter and then just calling print. However, using it properly (calling flush() and close()) ensured that all of the html was written to the file. Unfortunately I am still missing html so it means my request is wrong :/

Comment: but this is different issue ;)

Comment: turns out a cookie was being set that I need to include in my post (for those interested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gather all the essence of the comments. There is nothing wrong with your code here - using `EntityUtils` is the recomended way to deal with all kinds of responses. You have error in code that stores your response to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem, and solved it by ensuring lcosing the connection like :

```
} finally {
        try {
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            try {
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.warn("Error while flushing the response output connection. It will ensure to close the connection.", e);
            }

            if (null != httpResponse) {
                httpResponse.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ignore) {
        }
    }
```

Or event better with try-resources :

```
try(CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, context)){ 
  if (response.getEntity() == null){
    throw new NullPointerException("Unable to get html for: " + url);
  }
  String responseData = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
  EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
```