# HTTPClient hung or slow in multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using following version of `httpclient` api to call the rest webservice.
`httpcore4.4.9`
`httpclient 4.5.9`
I am using the `ExecutorService` to execute the task where it is calling my following methods to get the data from rest API. `ExecutorService` execute about 30+ rest call in one transaction and i observed that, `httpclient` HUNG or SLOW for few of the rest call and it hit the performance issue. Can you please check if below i am using `httpclient` correct way ?

````
        String output = null;
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = getHttpClients();

        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            output = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error during call to REST API " + httpGet.getURI() + "   ", e);
        } finally {
            httpClient.close();
            httpGet.releaseConnection();
            httpGet.abort();
        }
        return output;
    }

    private CloseableHttpClient getHttpClients() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = 0;
        int timeout = 12000;
        RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
        requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        requestBuilder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout);

        SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom().setSoTimeout(timeout).build();

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
        builder.disableContentCompression();
        builder.setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder
                .build();
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.debug("Total time took to build client = " + (endTime - startTime));
        return httpClient;
    } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, this problem is occurring because of `EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity())` .
You could find what it actually does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15970985/11537839).

Try removing and running your code to match the speed and decide if you want it or not.
Below is the code used by me:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
      String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
} catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error(ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust MaxTotal and MaxPerRoute variable in PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager class.

```
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(maxTotalConnections);
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute);
```